# Why my code fails to access parent gridview in rowcommand?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I have a **ParentGridview** which contains **ChildGridview** inside a **Panel** and inside an `**ItemTemplateField**`. Now in coding I want to get the **ParentGridview** and via that I want to access that **Panel** but can't achieve.

aspx: (`*`Don't go with the syntax, i just wrote it here in exact style of original code`*`)

```
<asp:gridview id="ParentGv" runat="server">
 <columns>
  <asp:templatefield>
  <itemtemplate>
    <asp:panel id="childpanel" runat="server">
      <asp:gridview id="ChildGv" runat="server"  onrowcommand="ChildGv_Rowcommand">
      <columns>
        <asp:templatefield>
         <itemtemplate>
            <asp:imagebutton id="btndelete" runat="server" CommandName="cmdDelete"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
         </itemtemplate>
        </asp:templatefield>         
      <columns/>
    </panel>
 </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
 </columns>
```

MyCode:

```
protected void ChildGv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView grdviewCaseHearingsDetails = (GridView)sender;

            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            if (e.CommandName == "cmdDelete")
            {
                GridView ChildGv = (GridView)((ImageButton)(e.CommandSource)).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
                GridView ParentGv = (GridView)(ParentGv.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent);

                ParentGv.FindControl("childpanel").Visible = true;
        }
```

but this keeps me giving the error at last line:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: man it's not a duplicate plus i am not that much qualified to understand it from general problem. Please remove the duplication

Comment: and i know that what a null exception is but in my case i cant figre out. Please help instead of sparing yourself by marking it as duplicate